# In python, why can't I use the extend function inside the print function?

Tags: python, list, printing, extend

If I write my code like this,

```
friends = ["Kafi", "Saif", "Shaheer", "Azmain", "Labid", "Faiz", "Azmain"]

lucky_numbers = [114, 151, 172, 7, 1, 63, 14, 543]

friends.extend(lucky_numbers)

print(friends)
```

then my code runs perfectly. But if I use the extend function inside the print function like this,

```
friends = ["Kafi", "Saif", "Shaheer", "Azmain", "Labid", "Faiz", "Azmain"]

lucky_numbers = [114, 151, 172, 7, 1, 63, 14, 543]

print(friends.extend(lucky_numbers))
```

then I get "None" as an output. Why can't I use the extend function inside the print function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print statement prints the return of `friends.extend(lucky_numbers)`, which is None.
From the docs:

*array.extend(iterable)* - 
Append items from iterable to the end of the array.

So `extend()` changes the array it is called on, but it doesnt return anything, ergo there is nothing to print.

Answer (score 1):

extend is in-place function that returns nothing.
Printing output from a function that hasn't returned anything will give you `None`
if you don't want to change `friends` then make a copy of it

```
newfriends = friends.copy()
newfriends.extend(lucky_numbers)
print(newfriends)
```